# resque-web issue with multiple instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

We're currently in transition between a Ruby/RoR 1.8/3.2 and a rewritten 2.0/4.0 app on the same server.  Since I don't want to mess with the current resque configuration and risk updating any gems that might break production, I elected to setup a separate Redis server on a new port and use the newest version of Resque with it.  Resque appears to be running fine; if I manually launch a worker `rake resque:work QUEUE='*'` and watch the process it runs a queued job from resque-scheduler.  However, none of my workers, launched manually or via script, show up in the resque-web instance running.  The stats page of resque-web shows it's looking at the second redis instance.  Does anyone have experience with this or any ideas?

## /config/initializers/resque.rb:

```
require 'resque_scheduler'
rails_root = ENV["RAILS_ROOT"] || File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../.."
rails_env = ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "demo"
resque_config = YAML.load_file(rails_root + "/config/resque.yml")
Resque.redis = resque_config[rails_env]
Resque.redis.namespace = "resque-reos:#{rails_env}"
```

## /config/resque.yml

```
demo: localhost:6380
```